# pyqt - Frameless widget weird titlebar appears

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I noticed a weird behavior when running a frameless widget in PyQt.
If I minimize it in taskbar multiple times, a Windows XP title bar appears in the top left corner during a few milliseconds and then disappears.

Here is a simple code to reproduce the problem :

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui.setWindowFlags(ui.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The behavior is described in this [video](http://sendvid.com/mw27863j)

My setup is Windows 7 (x64), Python 3.5 and PyQt5.7 
(FYI, the problem was also present in PyQt5.6)

Can anyone explain this behavior and give a solution ?

Comment: I have Windows 7 (x64), Python 3.5.2 (installed with Miniconda3) and PyQt5.6 and I do not see the effect. However I believe you, the video is clear. I think something weird goes on. Maybe try on another computer?

Comment: That's really weird, I tried with `QtCreator` version using the same code in C++, it happened too. I also installed `Windows 7 x64` on a new VM with only `Python 3.5.2 (x32)` and `PyQt5-5.6-gpl-Py3.5-Qt5.6.0-x32-2` and tried the code above and it happened also.. Are you using the x32 or x64 version of Python ?

Comment: everything is x64, maybe it's a bug of the x32 versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reported the [issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57099) to Qt and it seems to be a general Windows bug :

> Sergio Martins added a comment
>
> I can reproduce this problem with a pure Windows example, (passing WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX to CreateWindowEx()).
> Doesn't seem fixable, other than removing the minimize button capability.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still has problems with it:

- make the window translucent
- create a widget that u can use as a window

Example:

```
    class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

            self.width = 400
            self.height = 220

            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):

            self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
            self.setFixedSize(self.width, self.height)

            self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

            self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
            self.window.setStyleSheet("QWidget{background-color: #ffffff;}")
            self.window.setGeometry(0, 0, self.width, self.height)

            self.minimize_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.window)
            self.minimize_button.setGeometry(355, 2, 20, 20)
            self.minimize_button.clicked.connect(self.minimize_window)

        def minimize_window(self):
            self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized)
```

Now the title bar does not appear anymore, due to the window being invisible.